# SOLR - Alphanumeric sort with alphabets first

Tags: sorting, solr, solrj

I am trying to do alphanumeric sort on a string field in SOLR. Now the general solution proposed for this is to left pad numbers with 0s and do normal dictionary sort. But this will put numbers before alphabets, while my requirement is alphabets should come before numbers.

I am new to SOLR. I can implement this sort logic in a Java comparator, but I see I cannot use this in SOLR. I explored sorting with custom functions (ValueSource) in SOLR, but as I understand, they operate on a single document's field value(s) at a time and allows us to map those value(s) to another value (for eg: like a sum function). There is no comparator-like relative scoring functionality (i.e. comparing 2 documents at a time) from what I've seen so far. I read about custom similarity classes but I don't think they're applicable to this scenario (and might be overkill?)

So how can I achieve this? The only (extremely ugly and terrible) solution I could think of, is to write a custom SOLR function which surrounds any numbers in the string with flower brackets (which have the largest ASCII value in the table). For example: `a87` will transformed to `a{87}`. This pushes them to last.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I suggest to avoid any custom similarity implementation.

You can create an [analyzer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Analyzers) chain that put alphabets before numbers fitting your [your case](http://www.andornot.com/blog/post/Make-numbers-behave-when-sorting-alphanumerically-in-Solr.aspx). With the following chain `a87` will transformed to `a000087`. And if this does not fit your exactly requirement, using the regex you can mangle the field as you want.

```xml
<fieldType name="alphaNumericSort" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="false" omitNorms="true">
  <analyzer>
    <!-- KeywordTokenizer does no actual tokenizing, so the entire
         input string is preserved as a single token -->
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- The LowerCase TokenFilter does what you expect, which can be
         when you want your sorting to be case insensitive -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <!-- The TrimFilter removes any leading or trailing whitespace -->
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
    <!-- Left-pad numbers with zeroes -->
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
            pattern="(\d+)" replacement="00000$1" replace="all"
    />
    <!-- Left-trim zeroes to produce 6 digit numbers -->
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
            pattern="0*([0-9]{6,})" replacement="$1" replace="all"
    />
    <!-- Remove all but alphanumeric characters -->
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
            pattern="([^a-z0-9])" replacement="" replace="all"
    />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

If you don't have particular requirement regarding the creation of new fields, I'll suggest to create a new one in your `managed-schema` and copy there the original field.

```xml
<field name="myNewField" type="alphaNumericSort" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<copyField source="sourceField" dest="myNewField" />
```

If this still doesn't fit your problem, another solution is transform the original field into one or more new fields (always using the analyzer chains mentioned before) each of them containing alternatively the alphabetic and numeric part.

In this way you can sort the output passing the list of fields, in the order you need, to the standard `sort` query clause. For example:

```query
sort=fieldAlpha1 asc, fieldNumeric1 desc, fieldAlpha2 asc
```

Or in Solrj

```java
solrQuery.addSortField("fieldAlpha1", ORDER.asc);
solrQuery.addSortField("fieldNumeric1", ORDER.desc);
solrQuery.addSortField("fieldAlpha2", ORDER.asc);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! "You can create an analyzer chain that put alphabets before numbers" - I couldn't figure out how to do this. As I said, left padding alone isn't enough for me (since it puts numbers first). The link you provided also does the same. 
"using the regex you can mangle the field as you want" - does this mean I can use my flower bracket solution?
Regarding creating new fields, I don't think that will be feasible. I have 2500 such fields to sort alphanumeric, and creating new fields corresponding to each will lead to too many fields.

Comment: ..contd. This is why I wanted to make a custom function which returns the mangled value on-the-fly instead of storing it as field(s). Also, about your last point (multi-sorting) - wouldn't this fail if there are a lot of alternating alpha and num parts in a string? Like a100b200c300 for eg?

Comment: The custom function has effect also on the relevance and probably this is not what you want. Really do you have 2500 alphanumeric fields to sort? Could you please post a real sample of your data?

Comment: "custom function has effect also on the relevance" - Is that so? Even if i invoke it for sort only? like, &sort=myfunc(myfield)?

"do you have 2500 alphanumeric fields to sort?" - Yes, these are basically various possible features/attributes of a product, which will appear as facets (for filtering) and in search result documents (where user can sort by them). Each product has only ~40-50 such features, but all products put together have 2500 possible features.

Comment: Having "effect on the relevance" means that when you search something Solr returns what's more relevant basing its score on your custom function. I suggest to ask info in the Solr Community http://lucene.apache.org/solr/community.html

Comment: I am sorry I don't have real data at this point. We have this requirement and have created some dummy fields like feature1, feature2 etc for testing purposes. Field feature1 for example takes values like "0 volt", "No Charge", "15 volts" etc. Similarly the other 2500-odd fields might have some alphanumeric values.